# Delays in forEach loop and isDisplayed()

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach, webdriver-io

I'm trying to write test case in JavaScript with Webdriverio. I need to press buttons using forEach loop and verify that after clicking on button, the site scrolls to the correct place using isDisplayed().

```
describe('test_1', () => {
    it('Go to URL', async () => {
        await browser.url('https://github.com/');
        await browser.maximizeWindow();
    })
    it('Menu', async () => {
        var menu = await $('div[class*=sub-nav-mktg-links]');
        menu.scrollIntoView();
        var buttons = await $$('a[class*=sub-nav-mktg-link]');
        buttons.forEach(element => {
            element.click();
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` or `for...of` loop.

```js
describe('test_1', () => {
    it('Go to URL', async () => {
        await browser.url('https://github.com/');
        await browser.maximizeWindow();
    })
    it('Menu', async () => {
        var menu = await $('div[class*=sub-nav-mktg-links]');
        menu.scrollIntoView();
        var buttons = await $$('a[class*=sub-nav-mktg-link]');
        for(let btn of buttons) {
            await btn.click();
            // await other async stuff
        });
    })
})
```

`Array#forEach` will synchronously tee up a sequence of operations that will then run without waiting for one another.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Now I'd like to make screentshot of each element but it always overwrite the same filename

it('Pictures', async () => {
       var buttons = await $$('picture[class*=flex-justify-center]');
        var image = await $('div[class*=pr-5]');
        image.scrollIntoView();
        for(let btn of buttons) {
           await btn.click();
           await browser.pause(700);
           await image.isDisplayed();
           await image.saveScreenshot('./test/specs/home_task_5/btn.png');
        }
})